# use CEC with my TV

Tags: debian, hdmi

When I plug my [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) to my TV (which supports SimpLink, or respectively [CEC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#CEC)) the TV automatically turns on from standby. This is due to the fact that the Raspberry Pi also supports CEC: http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/1839

I would like to see this working with my HTPC aswell. It runs Debian Wheezy - the HDMI-connector is on a [ASUS P8H77-I](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/P8H77I/)-board.

How can I

1. check, if CEC is supported by my mainboard?
2. make CEC work if it's supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the specifications at the link you provided, I don't believe this motherboard has CEC support.  It's a fairly new standard, especially to the PC world..

You might try looking at http://www.pulse-eight.com/store/products/104-usb-hdmi-cec-adapter.aspx for an alternate solution.  I haven't tried the device as of yet, but it is an intriguing looking device.

Comment: thank you! After spending some hours on research, this was also my conclusion. I will contact ASUS to ask them if there is a way to make CEC work anyway. Do you have a clue if the usb-hdmi-cec adapter supports switching on the TV-screen from standby?

Comment: From everything I understand, the adapter should support just about anything that the CEC standard supports which does include standby switching as you have described.